# How to set up a project in VS2010 that can also be compiled from within VS with a different compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, configuration, cross-platform

I have a Visual Studio 2010 project with C++ code that I want to run on 2 Systems. I develop,compile,debug, etc. it in Visual 2010 but also have a separate batchfile with which I can compile some of the classes for a different system.

How do I have to set up the configuration manager (or do whatever else is necessary) so that I can run,debug,etc. my project normally in vs2010 with mfc/win32 and then switch to another, new configuration where only a batch file is being executed from vs2010 (and no longer the vs2010 compiler) and the results of that are being shown in the output window ?

Comment: You're probably better off using CMake to generate build configurations for each target.

Comment: Semi-guessing on this, but being a closed source, proprietary compiler and IDE, I really doubt that VS has some simple mechanism for just dropping another compiler in place and using its other tools.  What is the other compiler, by the way?  Might be a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: The other compiler is gcc 4.4.3 with which I create native C++ code for android 2.3.4 and is being executed by a batch file. I think it should somehow be possible to use a batch file instead of the internal compiler. All I need to know is how to create a configuration where the compiler does not run but a custom build step or some build event is being executed instead.

Comment: I doubt VS will let you bypass the compilation stage.  From the creators view point, that would be a really weird and pointless feature.  Somewhere deep in the project configuration though there might be something.

Comment: You might be able to do something with a pre-build event (calling your batch file) and somehow stopping the build in that same build event. I don't know how to do that though.

Comment: This is certainly _possible_, e.g., Intel C++ Compiler for Windows integrates quite nicely with Visual Studio and you can toggle a project between using icc and cl.  It's probably just a matter of writing your own MSBuild tasks to call gcc with the right options and then tweaking the project files to use those tasks instead of the Visual C++ tasks.  (I am not an MSBuild expert, so I cannot provide advice on what is the best way to go about doing this or whether this is at all advisable.  It just seems to me that you'd be much better off with CMake.) /cc @Corbin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by creating a new configuration in the configuration manager where I selected any kind of platform (doesn't matter for this) and then excluded all files from build with their individual file properties. The compiler has nothing to do then. So I added a custom build step in the project settings where my batch file is being executed. Now whenever I switch to this configuration in the menu only my batch file is being run and I can easily switch back to my normal debug profile for developing, testing and debugging in vs2010. Its not that elegant but it works...

Comment: It is possible to extend MSBuild to utilize GCC as the compiler by writing GCC specific targets files, as illustrated by this book,

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/deployment/9780735659827/extending-visual-cplusplus-2010/341#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODA3MzU2NTk4MjcvMzM4

However, there is no existing attempt reported over the net about this topic except that book.